# Oracle - Select rows from a table based on ID's stored in a column

Tags: oracle, subquery, substring

I have written a stored procedure to do some data matching. When it completes I update a MATCH_DETAILS column stating that it has matched with an ID but it could have matched with other ID's also.

I would like to write SQL to read from the table based on the list of ID's that I have specified in the MATCH_DETAILS column.

```
Matched with multiple QSIDs, updating with QSID: 6030066992. Possible QSIDs: 6030066992,1777,
```

So, my SQL would look for the text "Possible QSIDs: " and then pull the ID's after this.

I tried to write a bit of SQL but it doesn't do what I want, it just returns a string but I need individual ID's to do the overall search on:

```
select SUBSTR(cd.match_details,
                  INSTR(cd.match_details, 'Possible QSIDs: ', 1) + 16,
                  length(cd.match_details) - 1)
      from scv_client_details cd
     where cd.match_details like 'Matched with multiple QSIDs%'
```

This just returns this:

```
6030066992,1777,
3602,3600,
etc...
```

What I would ideally want is to return them as numbers with one per line I guess:

```
6030066992
1777
3602
3600
etc...
```

Anyone have any ideas what is required here?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; read comments within code:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with scv_client_details  (match_details) as
  2    (select 'Matched with multiple QSIDs, updating with QSID: 6030066992. Possible QSIDs: 6030066992,1777,'
  3     from dual
  4     union all
  5     select 'Matched with multiple QSIDs. Yet another example; Possible QSIDs: 12345,6789'
  6     from dual
  7    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  8  temp as
  9    -- return strings that follow "Possible QSIDs:"
 10    (select trim(replace(substr(match_Details, instr(match_details, 'Possible QSIDs:')),
 11                    'Possible QSIDs:',
 12                    null
 13                   )) val
 14     from scv_client_details
 15    ),
 16  temp2 as
 17    -- split previously fetched comma-separated strings to rows. Avoid duplicate rows!
 18    (select regexp_substr(val, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) val
 19     from temp cross join
 20       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 21                           connect by level <= regexp_count(val, ',') + 1
 22                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 23    )
 24  -- finally, result is numeric part of previously fetched VAL
 25  select regexp_substr(val, '\d+') result
 26  from temp2
 27  where regexp_like(val, '\d+');
```

Result:

```
RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6030066992
1777
12345
6789

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm only seeing your reply now, it never notified me of any reply, thanks so much... I am trying to adapt your SQL to have a select from the SCV_CLIENT_DETAILS table as the input instead of having to manually specify data. When I put in the select it is saying that I need to have UNION ALL in a recursive statement. I'm not sure what this means?

Comment: Got sorted thanks, I had to include a union, the second SELECT was made to just return nothing... Crude but it worked. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome; sorry for not replying sooner, I was absent. As of your problems: you don't need to UNION *anything* as you already have data stored in a table. I don't have it, so - for this example - I used a CTE (i.e. a WITH factoring clause) which is OK for demo purposes. Therefore: you'd just copy/paste code that begins at line #8 and precede it with the WITH keyword. So: `with temp as ...`, and the rest of query is *as is*.